# Is there a Stack Exchange community that went from self-governance (elected moderators) back to moderator appointment?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

I had a closer look at the Stack Exchange election procedures. As far as I understand, communities are at some point in time granted "self-governance", in terms of being allowed to hold elections of their moderators. I wondered, did elections procedures always worked out for all communities on Stack Exchange? Or is there a community that lost their self-governance status and had to go back to moderators being appointed by Stack Exchange (e.g., due to misbehavior of moderators or lack of community engagement)?

Comment: This would probably mean going from graduate back to beta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Once a site graduates and has a Moderator election, it's expected that that's how Moderators will be selected going forward.

In a situation where all of a site's Moderators needed to be removed for malfeasance, I would expect the Community Management team would step in to cover moderation duties until a new moderator election could be held. Since it's the Community Moderation team who determines when to have elections, I would expect one to be held in very short order.